# Open Xcode 4.3.1 in 32bit mode

Tags: macos, xcode4, osx-lion

I noticed after upgrading from 4.2 to 4.3.1 that there is no longer a 32 bit mode option in the Get Info for Xcode. How would I run Xcode 4.3.1 in 32 bit mode now?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Xcode is now 64-bit only -- there's no 32-bit code in it anymore.

If you had some plugins which were previously 32-bit only, you will need to upgrade them.

Answer (score 1):

If you run your mac in 32 bit mode (when you start the computeer with "3" and "2" key) you will have your machine and their programs in 32 mode.