# Compile large source files (10k+ lines) in Xcode 4.x

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, compilation, clang

I've got some source files ranging from 20,000 lines up to 120,000 lines each. They are made of simple (very long) functions, just a long series of calls to C methods (in Apple's API's - e.g. Quartz) and should be easy to compile.

However, Xcode takes hours to compile them, and it FORCES a re-compile seemingly every time the xcodeproj file changes (xcode bug?). Also, doing an Archive (for upload to App Store) causes a complete re-compile anyway.

These files are stupid-long - they're the output of a code-generating tool - and I may *eventually* be able to get them smaller - but surely there's a way to make clang work properly on files this length?

Things I've tried:

1. Run in 32bit mode - IMPOSSIBLE: Apple has now removed this feature https://stackoverflow.com/a/9791396/153422
2. Add more CPU / cores - NEGLIGIBLE EFFECT: clang is single-threaded on most operations
3. Add more RAM - NEGLIGIBLE EFFECT: 8 GB RAM was not noticeably better than 2 GB RAM (no surprise: it's only one file - very unlikely it's going to use up gigs of memory!)
4. Add an SSD drive - SMALL EFFECT: laptop with slightly slower CPU + SSD compiles slightly faster (10%?) than desktop with slightly faster CPU + normal HD
5. Disable SVG/GIT integration - NO EFFECT: Apple's implementation of SVN is so buggy that we have it turned off already - for ALL projects.
6. Disable OS X indexing - SMALL EFFECT: Apple's Spotlight / background indexing is broken in lots of ways. Turning it off made build times a little faster - but maybe because it makes Xcode faster generally.

Comment: pt.3) large compilations can be memory bound. memory exhaustion can certainly slow your build to a crawl. i've seen builds consume several GB of memory. as well, other stages can consume a lot of memory, depending on your files and build settings (e.g. linking)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean - as I said, adding RAM had no effect here

Comment: Have you tried different settings in the code generation tool?

Answer (score 1):

Possible approach:

- Convert your project to use makefiles by using [pbxbuild](https://github.com/gnustep/gnustep-pbxbuild)
- Call `gmake` with the option `-j [n]` (try for a good n)

Advantages:

- No xcodeproj file changes
- Utilization of paralle compiling

Comment: Am I correct in thinking GNUstep doesn't support the two Apple platforms that Xcode targets (OS X and iOS)? - "GNUstep currently supports Unix (GNU/Linux and GNU/HURD, Solaris, NetBSD, OpenBSD, FreeBSD, Darwin) and Windows.". I didn't think to include OS tag on the question - sorry! - but I've retagged now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating really long functions (thousands of lines long), you might want to consider splitting them into multiple smaller functions.

You could also try setting the optimization level to -O0 or -O1.

Also, please file a report at http://bugreporter.apple.com .

Comment: Putting them into a static lib, and then setting main project to -O0 helps a lot. -O fastest+smallest kills xcode brutally :(